# How to convert sql subselect query to hql?

Tags: sql, hibernate, subquery, hql

hi i want to convert my `sql subselect` query to `hql`. my sql query is shown below

```
select distinct sum(goal_score) from(
select user_id,max(goal_score) goal_score from sc_student_final_results ssfr
where month=8 and year=2013 group by goal_id,user_id) ssfr group by ssfr.user_id
```

for the abo native sql command i have converted to hql as shown below

```
select distinct sum(goalScore) FROM (select userId,max(goalScore) goalScore FROM 
StudentFinalResults sr where year=:year and month=:month and locationId =:siteid 
group by  userId,goalId) sr group by sr.userId
```

but i am getting the error

```
org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:37: unexpected token: (
org.hibernate.hql.PARSER - line 1:52: unexpected token: max
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 37 [select distinct sum(goalScore) 
FROM (select userId,max(goalScore) goalScore FROM
net.sankhya.scorecards.model.StudentFinalResults sr where year=:year and 
month=:month and locationId =:siteid group by userId,goalId) sr group by sr.userId]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query with this, it might work out!

```
select distinct sum(sr3.goalScore) FROM (select userId,max(goalScore)  FROM 
StudentFinalResults sr2 where year=:year and month=:month and locationId =:siteid 
group by  userId,goalId) sr3 group by sr3.userId
```